# Perpendicular Vector3 to a given Vector3

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I find a `Vector3` which is perpendicular to given `Vector3`?
Maybe rotate the `Vector3` 90 degrees or something, is there a vector3 function that can do that?

This image illustrates what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more detail? You can multiply vectors which can get you the same vector, but in a different direction. For example: `Vector3 newVector3 = originalVector3 * Vector3.right` gives you the originalVector but pointing to its right. This is relative though. Calculating quaternions might be more accurate and powerful, but it's far more complicated.

Comment: over the course of editing your question you have inherently changed it. you shouldn't do that, people have put work into writing answers. instead write a new question. The answer you gave yourself does not even answer the original question.
even worse, you never updated the title. Now the only accepted answer does not answer the question posed in the title.

Comment: You can edit your question to make the meaning more clear (not change it). if you do, rewrite the text and not lazily append "Edit.." https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/316262

Comment: I rolled back your question one edit. Now all the original answers are valid again. I would ask you to unaccept your own answer and optionally choose a different one, as it does not longer answer your question

Comment: thanks for changing the accepted answer. In turn I have slightly improved your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing is, there is an infinite amount of vectors perpendicular to any given vector in 3D space. You need a second vector not parallel to the first one to find a vector perpendicular to them both, i.e. their [cross product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product),  since this way a plane is defined, which may have only one perpendicular line.

In Unity, cross product is computed by the static method `Vector3.Cross()`.

Comment: This feels like a major milestone for me... I published my first game 9 years ago, but this is the first time I ever used `Vector3.Cross()`... and it worked beautifully the first time and I understand why. No longer is it arcane magic that I've merely heard of but am too scared to use.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your original question: how to compute a vector perpendicular to another?

Let's call your vector `p` and the vector we're looking for that is perpendicular to it `q`. Note that there are an infinite number of vectors `q` but we're just going to find one.

For perpendicular vectors the dot product is always `0` so we find the equation `p · q = 0` which we can write as `p.x * q.x + p.y * q.y + p.z * q.z = 0`. Now we're going to assign arbitrary values to `q.x` and `q.y` in order to fix one solution, let's pick `q.x = 1` and `q.y = 1`. Then we're left with `p.x + p.y + p.z * q.z = 0`. Solving for `q.z` gives us `q.z = -(p.x + p.y) / p.z`.

In conclusion: the vector `q = (1, 1, -(p.x + p.y) / p.z)` is perpendicular to `p`.

Comment: Doesn't this fail for particular values of p? Like when its parallel to your arbitrary values?

Comment: If you consider infinite numbers as invalid, yes, there are some values that fail, namely values of `p` that have `p.z = 0`. In this case you'll get a division by 0 and the value `q.z` will be infinite. To get around this you could check if `p.z` is 0 and then choose either `q.x` or `q.y` as your free variable. If all of the 3 values are 0 then you have the zero vector for which perpendicular is not well defined.

Answer (score 1):

This perpendicular vector in 3D space is not unique. However, given another vector, you can obtain a new vector which is perpendicular to both of them.

```
Vector3 v1;
Vector3 v2;
Vector3 v3 = Vector3.Cross(v1, v2);
```